# Does the word " Humble " mean "at least" here?

Tags: meaning

I have been reading an experience told by someone about her hen. This is the sentence :

> She never fully recovered (always had the limp and almost useless left leg), but died at a VERY **humble** 12 years old...yep...that is NOT a misprint...she was 12 years old when she died!

I wanted to know that does the word "humble" there mean "at least"?

This is the whole story:

> My first hen, Emma, was "orphaned" as an adult when her keeper, who was in her 90's died. 
>   She was about 3 years old when we took her in, and then she had a stroke.
>   She did the same thing...would eat and lay, but couldn't walk.
>   After hours and hours of me working with her and getting her to try to walk, she started being able to with a huge limp.
>   She never fully recovered (always had the limp and almost useless left leg), but died at a VERY humble 12 years old...yep...that is NOT a misprint...she was 12 years old when she died!
>
> No one believes me until I show pictures of me and Emma, with me being little holding her, then bigger, then bigger, then finally, *I* am an adult in the pictures...haha
>
> Don't give up hope...a stroke doesn't always mean the end, especially for a pet hen, even when others that are "pros" are saying "it's time for the stew pot".

Comment: Was this written by a native English speaker? "...died at **a** (very humble) 12 years old" sounds wrong in many ways - you have the indefinite article with plural; at n years old is unidiomatic (it is either died at the age of 12 or was 12 years old when she died). It is difficult to interpret the meaning of a word in context where the language  is questionable - the word may have been misused.

Comment: I would say that the chicken lived well beyond the average lifespan, and that *humble* here refers to the infirmities of old age.  The language of the excerpt is perfectly idiomatic. (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22died%20at%20an%20age%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, [**humble**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/humble) means :

> Near the ground; **not high** or lofty; not pretentious or magnificent; unpretending; unassuming; as, a humble cottage.

It is **opposed to [*venerable age*](https://www.google.de/search?q=he+died+at+a+venerable+age&oq=he+died+at+a+venerable+age&gs_l=serp.3...3862.30892.0.31035.41.40.1.0.0.2.600.6559.1j11j6j2j3j2.25.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..22.19.4058.EDJaciqftCE)** on which you should have achieved "great" things like raised a family or owned a house.

Comment: A humble cottage I can understand;  a humble 12 years old, not so much.

Comment: According to a quick Google search, 8 years is average lifespan.

Comment: @Yohann V.: The piece is about a *hen*, not about humans.

Comment: @TRomano The purpose of the story is to be misleading Emma for a human and not a hen, this is the punch-line of the joke and is not discovered before or in the sentence the OP is asking about. So, *"humble"* is perfectly leading to think Emma is young.

Answer (score 0):

'Humble' is usually used to mean simple, or unassuming or modest. It's usage here is wrong - 'respectable' would be a good replacement. ('A very respectable age' is idiomatic in the UK meaning a long life).

Comment: Any explanation forthcoming on the downvote?